# Get value of object by knowing an other value of this object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Okay so I have this object:

```js
const command = {
    hello: {
        name: "ohayo",
        aliases: ["hi"]
    }
};
```

and I want to get the name of "hello" just by knowing an aliase...

I tried this:

```js
console.log(command.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes("hello")));
```

but it returned this error:
`TypeError: command.find is not a function`

Here is the snippet:

```js
const command = {
    hello: {
        name: "hello",
        aliases: ["hi"]
    }
};

console.log(command.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes("hello")));
```

Comment: `command` is an object, so of course it doesn't have a `.find` array method

Comment: okay, sure but how can I achieve what I need to do?

Comment: Search `Object.values(command)`

Comment: `Object.values(command).find(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) because `command` is an object not an array

```js
const command = {
    hello: {
        name: "hello",
        aliases: ["hi"]
    }
};

Object.values(command).find(cmd => console.log(cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes("hello")));
```